# War bonus on clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm the clan leader and the highest level in everything compared to other members but their war bonus is always double mine, why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Basics:

War bonus is determined by the base that you attack and your town hall level. When you select an enemy base, the bonus will be visible in the rectangle that pops up (the one with the options to scout and attack). The higher up the base, the bigger the war loot will be if you are victorious in your attack.

To answer your question, yes, if you attack a town hall below yours, you get a 'penalty'. I just tested a few numbers and asked some fellow friends what they see as war bonus and I have the numbers confirmed to be just like the normal loot penalty figures:

Here's a table:

```
Town Hall level difference  |    Percentage of War 
                            |   bonus loot available
----------------------------+------------------------
Same or higher level        |          100%
1 level lower               |           90%
2 levels lower              |           50%
3 levels lower              |           25%
4 or more levels lower      |            5%
```

Comment: I'm attacking the highest base with highest war bonus and it says a different amount for the same base for my friends example I attack there number 1 base and it says 142000 war bonus but for my friend to attack the same base its like 400000 and I'm a higher level than my friend

Comment: @Dan Oh? Ok, that is new to me. I will ask a few friends and see if that's the same where I am and let you know. Supercell might have changed a few things in the last updates.

Comment: Ok thanks it's annoying as all me group are getting more bonus than me lol

Comment: If you're higher than your friend and you're attacking the same base then logically you should get less

Comment: @Dan I stand corrected, and have done some calculations to get the exact difference in war loot bonus; added in my answer.